# Angular ng-option not creating any options

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking at this for too long and can't figure out why the options aren't showing up.  Using 1.2.26

```
{{students}}
<select name="student" ng-options="i.id as i.first_name for i in students"></select>
```

So this outputs a select but no options. students is populated and displays as

```
[{"first_name":"Student","last_name":"Seven","email":"","order":"0","id":11,"rLevel":2},{"first_name":"Student","last_name":"Eight","email":"","order":"6","id":12,"rLevel":2},{"first_name":"Student","last_name":"Six","email":"","order":"2","id":10,"rLevel":2},{"first_name":"Studen","last_name":"Four","email":"","order":"1","id":8,"rLevel":2}]
```

I know angular is initialized and students is an array of objects.  This loop just below the select outputs and functions as it should.

```
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">
      <a href="#" ng-click="addStudent(student.id)">{{student.first_name}} {{student.last_name}}</a> <span ng-show="student.id == class.current_student.id"></span>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ng-model` attribute on your select. `ng-options` only works with `ng-model`, otherwise it has nowhere to bind to.

Also, I just noticed [line 388](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js#L388) of the select directive source. That relies on the `ngModelController`'s `render` functionality to actually populate the options in the DOM.